# Cannot modify dictionaries inside dictionaries using Managers from multiprocessing?

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

I wrote some code like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def f(m, d, i):
    d['d'] = m.dict()
    d['d'][i] = i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()

    d = manager.dict()

    for i in range(10):
        p = Process(target=f, args=(manager, d, i))
        p.start()
        p.join()

    print d
```

And I pretended to get the following result:

```
{'d': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}}
```

but it didn't work and I got:

```
{'d': {}}
```

I am very confused about this and searched via google and find this website -- http://bugs.python.org/issue6766

Is it an existed issue or fixed? And what can I do to realize this function?

Comment: The issue has "open" status in the bug tracker.

Comment: Take a look at the [Manager documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers). Scroll a little down, and you'll see a note: "Modifications to mutable values or items in dict and list proxies will not be propagated through the manager, because the proxy has no way of knowing when its values or items are modified. To modify such an item, you can re-assign the modified object to the container proxy." Perhaps you'll have to re-assign the sub-dictionary within `d`

Comment: E.g: `subdict = m.dict()`, `subdict[i] = i`, and finally, `d['d'] = subdict`

Comment: Take a look at [Pipes and Queues](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) for inter-process communication.